# How open Url after Firebase message received in background

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

When application is in background and Firebase message received I want to open specific url that is in message data.
For example i put below key-value in Firebase and i want to open google site after user tap on notification.

```
key: url
value: http://google.com
```

what should i do?
tnx in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your application you can access the key/value pairs sent from `Advanced options > Custom data` in the Firebase Notification Web console in these ways:

- `getIntent().getExtras()` in the activity that is launched when the user tap the notification.
  I recommend to add this in the activity `onResume()` method.
- `remoteMessage.getData()` in `FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived()` if the application is already open when the message arrives. (in this case the notification is not shown and instead the `onMessageReceived()` is invoked.

Comment: Tnx Diego, your answer in correct. I write getExtras() in onCreate() method and startActivity for showing url in browser but I want solution that don't launch my application when push notification come from Firebase. do you have any idea?